# Android gps location real accuracy is bad

Tags: android, gps

I get location in LocationListener configured with following code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 5.0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5.0, locationListener);
```

Locations which I get are innacurate very often. Accuracy in location for "gps" provider is about 10-20 m, but in real it can be about 500 m. And in native Android application Google Maps I see my location accurate enough.

I have suspicion that Google use some another API. Is there present another way to get locations in Android?

- OS: Android 4.4
- Smartphone model: Doogee Voyager 2 DG310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google apps use a proprietary provider called "Fused Location Provider" ([read more here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)). This provider still uses the network and GPS providers present in the background.

The first location fix from network provider will most of the time be grater than 1000 m in accuracy because it comes from a BTC (cell tower). After a few seconds it should drop to around 20-50 m accuracy based on Wi-Fi. The GPS provides locations usually with max accuracy 20 m but this can increase when you're in a densely populated area with tall buildings and bad connection to GPS satellites.

I recently discovered the [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) which should provide easy access to either GPS, network or fused providers in combination with Activity Recognition to decrease battery drain.